# Is there a way to return custom objects similar to a .Success response. ardalis result

Tags: .net-core, ardalis-cleanarchitecture, ardalis-specification

I've been attempting to return a custom object with a 'Error' status, but I'm facing difficulties in implementing it.

Success return looks like this

```
return Result<customObject>.Success(customObject);
```

However, I would like the code to resemble this instead:

```
return Result<customObject>.Error(customObject);
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the object passed to Error cannot be converted to a 'string'. Is there a way to do it the same way with return success?